# Custom string instead of "Object" in console.log

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For convenience while debugging, I think it would be nice to print some custom string, rather than the default `Object` that appears when logging an object to the console.

In the following example, see how an object called `example` is marked by `Object` when it is logged to the console, whereas `window` is marked by `Window` when it is logged to the console. I guessed that the `__proto__["Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)"]` property might be the way to go, since `window`'s is set to `Window`. That didn't work, but maybe I'm just using it wrong.

[image]

Comment: That's because `window` is an instance of `Window`... and `example` is an instance of `Object`.

Comment: As I understand it, Window is an Object. So, how did the marking change from Object to Window and how can I do that with my own Objects?

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use the symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using the Symbol wrong -- you were on the right track. `Symbol.toStringTag` is a special well-known Symbol used by `Object#toString` to give you the console output, specifically the tag you're after. You can't wrap it in a string as you've done, or else you'll be literally setting the `"Symbol.toStringTag"` property, not the actual Symbol:

```js
const example = {
  key: "value"
};

example.__proto__["Symbol.toStringTag"] = "Example";
console.log(example); //You set the literal "Symbol.toStringTag" property -- wrong
```

Instead, don't wrap it in quotes and actually set the Symbol:

```js
const example = {
  key: "value"
};

example.__proto__[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Example";
console.log(example);
```

Which produces (on Chrome):

[image]

Comment: @K.Rohde Browser compatibility says only IE doesn't support it yet

Comment: In Chrome, it worked. In Edge it displayed [object Object]. In IE it says, "''Symbol' is undefined". In Firefox it displayed Object.

Comment: @hutch90 Hmm, I guess. It's in the [ECMAScript 2015 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-symbol.tostringtag) so Chrome's the only one that complies. It'll probably be supported in the future I suppose.

Comment: @AndrewLi Well, this works for me. I do my debugging in Chrome for the most part.